# Ajax/ JQuery : Dynamically Update a text box value without reloading a page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get the current value of a span element

```
<span class="accessTokenDisplaySand keyValues" id="sandAccess" data-value="7becc08d7f98bbaa9cb664f6d5731efb">7becc08d7f98bbaa9cb664f6d5731efb</span>
```

The `data-value` is important here. 
I can regenerate this value using a button click. A random value is generated for that.

On the other page I need to display this value in a text box when an option of a select box is clicked.

I open two tabs in my browser one each for the two web pages.
I Regenerate this data-value of the span by clicking a button. Then without refreshing the other page I click the option value corresponding to that value in the other page to display the value in the text box.

I have written the `document.ready()` function to display the corresponsing value according to the option value in the second page.

But if I regenerate the span value in the first page and click on the other page I cannot get the newly generated value. It shows the previously generated value.

Hoe I can use `JQuery/ Ajax` to get this updated dynamically without reloading the second page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't need to use ajax or any server-side handling if you store the value in the `LocalStorage` or `SessionStorage` for the page/site. You can use one of these `Storage` objects to store the value so that it is available to other pages on the site as well as create event listeners for when the storage changes so that a page can perform some action whenever the value in the storage is changed from a different page.

What you would want to do is:

1. When the regenerate button is clicked on pageA, in addition to whatever you are already doing, store/update the new value in `LocalStorage` (going to use `LocalStorage` from here on, but `SessionStorage` may be what you want).
2. On pageB, populate the input field value with the value stored in the storage object and add an event listener to LocalStorage that triggers when the value changes (which could be on pageA or pageB) and updates the input value.

part 1:

```
// put inside the regenerate functionality

 localStorage.setItem('sand-access-key', new_key_value);
```

part 2:

```
// From pageB:

var key_field = document.getElementById("sand_key_input");

window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
    if(e.key == 'sand-access-key') {
         key_field.val = e.newValue;
    }
});
```